# Jquery navigation hidden by another slideshow.js

Tags: jquery

Need help with multiple .js on a page. The jsddm navigation script is hidden by the slideshow.js.

Greatly appreciate on any advise how I can reflect the navigation on the top layer.

example here: http://clashboomband.com/test/test.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your z-index in you CSS. The header needs to be above the slide show.